# Removing corrupt object

Tags: objects, scene, append

I have a corrupt object in my master scene. It can't be seen anywhere else than in the outliner. I can select it (in the outliner) but I can't delete it.

It happen to be so that this corrupt/lost object is in all my blender files because they where based on the same blender file.

I know I can Append/Link all objects into a new blender file, but the problem is that I have quite some node setups in the compositor. The only way to append them is to append the scene itself but that will also include my corrupted object.

I tried to copy/paste the nodes into the new blend file, but all my node groups complained about an empty datablock, so that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

I'm using Blender 2.68a with Cycles.

Comment: Aren't node groups (compositor or material) included in the `Node tree` folder when appending?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to it :)

In the Outliner, change from "All Scenes" to "Blender File" right click on the corrupted object and select "Delete". Now it is deleted...

Comment: You're having some weird problems ;) are you using a build downloaded from blender.org or builder.blender.org?

Comment: No I use the official binary from blender.org

Comment: If you know the name, you could also use the Python Console I guess.